# How to add a group-accessible shared file folder to the Files folder in E.G.?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I want to have a shared folder inside my SAS server. Very much like a library but where a small group can store and share `.sas` code files and browser them inside the SAS Eguide.

I don't want stored processes, because people should directly access and edit the source code inside there local eguide flow.

Can I add a folder to the Files folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the file system, add a symlink/short cut to the shared location where the files folder points.

Answer (score 0):

In your Enterprise Guide, if it has the same standard setup as mine,
you can save a PROJECT which file extension is .EPG directly in your metadata server.
Since a project is a collection of sas programs.
 "Shared Data", that is present in every metadataserver configuration, is the metafolder where you can create a folder, if you have the permissions, where save your project that can be shared with anyone of your group that can have permissione to read/write that metafolder.

I suggest this way since it's a way to embed and share easily projects, and so sas programs.